# Reports SSRS deployment issue in dynamics ax

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I have create my report in visual studio and i can't deploy it;
I have deploy my report by 3 different ways  : Through AOT,Through Visual Studio,Through PowerShell ; but i have the same issue 
i have this error message:

```
The deployment was canceled due to an error. On the report server, make sure: 
- SQL Server Reporting Services service is running. 
- SQL Server Reporting Services service is configured according to the instructions in the manual installation of Microsoft              Dynamics AX (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=163796). 
- The remote administration functionality is allowed to communicate through the Windows Firewall.
```

I have Run this command  `Test-AXReportServerConfiguration`  in AX power shell  and this is the message in screen shot

```
IsAOSRunning                  : True

IsCurrentUserAdminOnAOSServer : True

IsCurrentUserAdminOnSRSServer : True

IsReportManagerRunning        : True

IsReportServerRunning         : False

IsUACDisabledOnAOSServer      : True

IsUACDisabledOnSRSServer      : True

Testing the report server configurations completed.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From your output, it looks like your report server isn't running or your report server URL isn't accessible:

`IsReportServerRunning         : False`

My output (AX 12 R2 CU7):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> test-axreportserverconfiguration
Testing the report server configurations.
Is Microsoft Dynamics AX Application Object Server running: True
Is the current user an administrator on the Microsoft Dynamics AX Application O
bject Server: True
Is the current user an administrator on the report server: True
Is the report server manager URL accessible: True
Is the report server URL accessible: True
Is User Account Control (UAC) disabled on the Microsoft Dynamics AX Application
 Object Server: True
Is User Account Control (UAC) disabled on the report server: True

Testing the report server configurations completed.
```

Comment: i checked the report server it's running

Comment: Check your .Net BC configuration (Control Panel>Administrative tools>Dynamics AX Client config) and .Net BC user (Under SystemAdministration>Setup>System>System service accounts).  Are both your `http://localhost/ReportServer` and `http://localhost/Reports` URLs accessible from your AOS user?

Comment: I'm check that  they are both the URL

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolve the problem   , it seems that it is a beast error

when i  GO to SysAdmin Module setup->Business Intelligence->Report Services->Report Servers , i have the  server name by lowercase , it should be to upercase
Here i'm have

```
IsAOSRunning                  : True

IsCurrentUserAdminOnAOSServer : True

IsCurrentUserAdminOnSRSServer : True

IsReportManagerRunning        : True

IsReportServerRunning         : True

IsUACDisabledOnAOSServer      : True

IsUACDisabledOnSRSServer      : True

Testing the report server configurations completed.
```

Finaly i can deploy my report

THank you

Comment: I would guess that is a coincidence, because my server name is mixed-case and it doesn't cause an issue.  More likely, re-typing the server name, you probably re-saved the record and hit the `*.update()` method or something like that which corrected data.